# How to fix responsive image bug in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a responsive theme on wordpress. When i'm on a desktop resolution, the thumbnails are 100% adjusted to the card, but when i reduce the resolution to a mobile device, it gets bigger than the card. Why is it happening?

I have already tried to add the bootstrap 4 responsive image class.

```
<section id="blog" class="blog  d-flex align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">

  <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); ?>


  <div class="container">
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">

 <h1>ÚLTIMAS<BR>PUBLICAÇÕES</h1> </div>    <div class="row">


      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-4 mt-3">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>" class="rounded-top"></a>
        <div class="card-body border rounded-bottom">

          <h4 class="card-title border-bottom pb-3 "><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h4>
          <p class="card-text"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Continuar lendo</a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>




    </div>
</section>
```

Expected:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

The thumbnail size configured on wordpress admin panel is 350 x273px

Answer (score 0):

Please add "img-responsive" class to your image. Correct code should be

```
<section id="blog" class="blog  d-flex align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">

  <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); ?>


  <div class="container">
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">

 <h1>ÚLTIMAS<BR>PUBLICAÇÕES</h1> </div>    <div class="row">


      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-4 mt-3">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>" class="rounded-top img-responsive"></a>
        <div class="card-body border rounded-bottom">

          <h4 class="card-title border-bottom pb-3 "><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h4>
          <p class="card-text"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Continuar lendo</a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Target your image with some CSS that keeps its width in check. You currently have class `rounded-top`, so you could add this CSS:

```
.rounded-top {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by addin  .card-img to the img tag.

Thank you all for the answers.